# Is it possible to prevent an iOS app from being placed on the home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, icons, homescreen

I am developing an iOS app using Xamarin.iOS that should only be triggered by tapping on a URL.  Because of this, I would like to prevent the app icon from being placed on the home screen.  The reason is, the app will not function properly if they open it from the home screen (it needs some of the data in the URL to load properly).  I would prefer to prevent the app from being on the home screen instead of checking whether a link was tapped or not.  I know that is possible to do this in Android using the manifest, is this also possible in iOS?

Comment: I think i is not possible. And also maybe the app will get rejected if the app will not work properly when you open it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible whatsoever; the developer has no control as to the placement and visibility of the application, and as such will always be visible on the springboard/home screen.

The best option you have is to show information to the user that explains why opening it from the home screen will not work, if they launch it that way. Most likely though, this will be rejected from the App Store as having no useful purpose. The guidelines are found here ([App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)), and I think this is what may cause a rejection (emphasis mine):

> If your app is not particularly useful, unique, **or “app-like,”** it doesn’t belong on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not finding the documentation I was looking for, but, as far as I know, this is not possible in iOS.

You could maybe have a default url that the app launches with and then use deep linking to launch the app with a custom urls. There are lots of great tutorials on deep linking (launching your app through a url) like
[This one](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/) or maybe [this one](http://blog.nbostech.com/2016/03/deeplinking-in-ios-using-swift/)

Comment: I have the deep linking stuff working; I was just wondering if it was possible to remove the app from the home screen since it will never work properly if they do.  My solution will be to to check the URL passed into the main controller, if it is null or an empty string, display a page telling the user they can only use the app by clicking on a valid link.

Comment: Yeah I understood your question which is why my first line says, no, I don't think this is possible. If your app is not on the home screen it is not installed. Most things are usually pretty black and white with Apple.
 Everything after that was just a suggestion on how you could create a workaround as your second choice.